# How to link to image on the web in a WebView

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, cocoa, mac-app-store

I have an HTML app running inside a Cocoa WebView and I am trying to link to an external image on the web. When I run the application in a regular browser the image shows fine, but if I run my Cocoa app the image does not resolve.

```
<img src="http://doubletapsoftware.com/logoheader_small.png" />
```

See image below.

[image]

Do I need to add any configuration in order to load images from the web?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I needed to change my sandboxing settings to allow outgoing connections.